# Can I placement new a std::tuple into a memory mapped region, and read it back later?

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files, reinterpret-cast, stdtuple

I have some packed structs which I will be writing to a memory mapped file. They are all POD.

To accommodate some generic programming I'm doing, I want to be able to write a `std::tuple` of several packed structs.

I'm worried that writing the members of a `std::tuple` to my mapped region's address, and then later casting that address back to a `std::tuple` is going to break.

I've written a small examplar program, and it does *seem* to work, but I'm worried that I have undefined behaviour.

Here are my structs:

```
struct Foo
{
    char    c;    
    uint8_t pad[3];
    int     i;                   
    double  d;                   

} __attribute__((packed));

struct Bar
{
    int     i;                   
    char    c;                   
    uint8_t pad[3];
    double  d;                   

} __attribute__((packed));
```

I define a `std::tuple` of these structs:

```
using Tup = std::tuple<Foo, Bar>;
```

To simulate the memory mapped file I have created a small object with some inline storage and a size:

When adding a tuple it uses placement new to construct the tuple in the inline storage.

```
struct Storage
{
    Tup& push_back(Tup&& t)
    {
        Tup* p = reinterpret_cast<Tup*>(buf) + size;
        new (p) Tup(std::move(t));

        size += 1;

        return *p;
    }

    const Tup& get(std::size_t i) const
    {
        const Tup* p = reinterpret_cast<const Tup*>(buf) + i;
        return *p;
    }

    std::size_t  size = 0;
    std::uint8_t buf[100];
};
```

To simulate writing to a file and then reading it again I create one `Storage` object, populate it, copy it, and then let the original go out of scope.

```
Storage s2;

// scope of s1
{
    Storage s1;

    Tup t1 = { Foo { 'a', 1, 2.3 }, Bar { 2, 'b', 3.4 } };
    Tup t2 = { Foo { 'c', 3, 5.6 }, Bar { 4, 'd', 7.8 } };

    Tup& s1t1 = s1.push_back(std::move(t1));
    Tup& s1t2 = s1.push_back(std::move(t2));

    std::get<0>(s1t1).c = 'x';
    std::get<1>(s1t2).c = 'z';

    s2 = s1;
}
```

I then read my tuples using `Storage::get` which just does a `reinterpret_cast<Tup&>` of the inline storage.

```
const Tup& s2t1 = s2.get(0);
```

When I access the structs within the tuple they have the correct values.

In addition, running through valgrind doesn't throw up any errors.

- Is what I'm doing defined behaviour?
- Is it safe to `reinterpret_cast` from my inline storage to `std::tuple` if the tuple was originally placement newed there (into a file which will be closed and then later remapped and reread)?

**Memory mapped file:**

The *actual* storage I use is a struct cast onto a `boost::mapped_region`.

The struct is:

```
struct Storage
{
    std::size_t  size;
    std::uint8_t buf[1]; // address of buf is beginning of Tup array
};
```

I cast it as follows:

```
boost::mapped_region region_ = ...;
Storage* storage = reinterpret_cast<Storage*>(region_.get_address());
```

Will the alignment issues mentioned in answers below be a problem?

**Full example below:**

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

struct Foo
{
    char    c;    
    uint8_t pad[3];
    int     i;                   
    double  d;                   

} __attribute__((packed));

struct Bar
{
    int     i;                   
    char    c;                   
    uint8_t pad[3];
    double  d;                   

} __attribute__((packed));

using Tup = std::tuple<Foo, Bar>;

struct Storage
{
    Tup& push_back(Tup&& t)
    {
        Tup* p = reinterpret_cast<Tup*>(buf) + size;
        new (p) Tup(std::move(t));

        size += 1;

        return *p;
    }

    const Tup& get(std::size_t i) const
    {
        const Tup* p = reinterpret_cast<const Tup*>(buf) + i;
        return *p;
    }

    std::size_t  size = 0;
    std::uint8_t buf[100];
};

int main ()
{
    Storage s2;

    // scope of s1
    {
        Storage s1;

        Tup t1 = { Foo { 'a', 1, 2.3 }, Bar { 2, 'b', 3.4 } };
        Tup t2 = { Foo { 'c', 3, 5.6 }, Bar { 4, 'd', 7.8 } };

        Tup& s1t1 = s1.push_back(std::move(t1));
        Tup& s1t2 = s1.push_back(std::move(t2));

        std::get<0>(s1t1).c = 'x';
        std::get<1>(s1t2).c = 'z';

        s2 = s1;
    }

    const Tup& s2t1 = s2.get(0);
    const Tup& s2t2 = s2.get(1);

    const Foo& f1 = std::get<0>(s2t1);
    const Bar& b1 = std::get<1>(s2t1);

    const Foo& f2 = std::get<0>(s2t2);
    const Bar& b2 = std::get<1>(s2t2);

    assert(f1.c == 'x');
    assert(f1.i == 1);
    assert(f1.d == 2.3);

    assert(b1.i == 2);
    assert(b1.c == 'b');
    assert(b1.d == 3.4);

    assert(f2.c == 'c');
    assert(f2.i == 3);
    assert(f2.d == 5.6);

    assert(b2.i == 4);
    assert(b2.c == 'z');
    assert(b2.d == 7.8);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is using something like `Boost::serialization` not feasible? I feel what you're doing is fine, as long as the application that wrote the memory and the application that reads it were compiled identically, ie are the same. Using a library though is much safer than serialization by hand, which from what I can determine, is effectively what you are doing.

Comment: I'm using memory mapped files because the quantity of data is so large I need to try eek out as much speed wherever I can. As it is a single run takes several days to complete. Hence writing pod directly to a mapped address. The caveats you specified do apply (same reading/writing code, application, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may like to align `std::uint8_t buf[100]` storage because unaligned access is undefined behaviour:

```
aligned_storage<sizeof(Tup) * 100, alignof(Tup)>::type buf;
```

(originally you had 100 bytes, this is for 100 `Tup`s).

When you map pages they start on at least 4k boundary on x86. If your storage starts on a page start then that storage is suitably aligned for any power-2 alignment up to 4k.

---

> I'm worried that writing the members of a `std::tuple` to my mapped region's address, and then later casting that address back to a `std::tuple` is going to break.

As long as the applications communicating through mapped memory use the same ABI, that works as expected.

Comment: If the storage is actually cast from the mapped region it will be page aligned though right?

Comment: I've updated the question to show how storage is actually a memory mapped region. Does the alignment issue still apply?

Comment: @SteveLorimer When you map pages they start on at least 4k boundary on x86. In other words, if your storage starts on a page start then that storage is suitably aligned for any power-2 alignment up to 4k.

Comment: Thanks Max! I guess there's no way to specify alignment on my `uint_8t buf[1]` "marker" array is there?

Comment: @SteveLorimer There is `alignas(64) uint_8t buf[1];`. However, that only affects alignment when the object is created on the stack. When allocating in mapped memory you need to make sure that the structure is aligned.

Answer (score 2):

```
Tup* p = reinterpret_cast<Tup*>(buf) + size;
new (p) Tup(std::move(t));
```

is undefined behaviour since `buf` might not be properly aligned for a `Tup`. The correct way of doing such thing is to use `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: If the storage is actually cast from the mapped region it will be page aligned though right?

Comment: I've updated the question to show how storage is actually a memory mapped region. Does the alignment issue still apply?

Comment: please use [std::allign](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align)

Comment: How can I account for the fact it is `std::uint8_t buf[1]`?

Comment: @SteveLorimer You cannot. One byte is not large enough for your `std::tuple<Foo, Bar>`

Comment: Yes, but I'm using it as a placeholder for the fact it's an address mapped from a file. I'm using a memory mapped file. Hence I cast the address of the mapped region (which is page aligned I believe) to my storage struct. I make mention of the fact I'm using a memory mapped file in the title.

Comment: Why don't just use the proper type? Regarding allignment ... two answerers allready told you to use `std::allign`.

Comment: Please edit your answer to show me how. I am still uncertain how to take a random memory address received from mapping a file and coersce it to the correct alignment.